# UITableViewCell Sorting

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am a beginner when it comes to Objective-C and I am hoping you experts can help me out. I have a web service that returns name and address with JSON encoding. On my app side I have a `UITableView` with subtitle style cells. I am showing Name for the main label and distance of address from current device location in second label. I have to sort `UITableViewCell` on distance. I am able to display name and distance but don't know how to sort on distance. I'll appreciate any help.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *sName = [info objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *sAddress = [info objectForKey:@"Address"];

    cell.textLabel.text = sName;

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:sAddress completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        } else {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

            CLLocation *restLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:placemark.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:placemark.location.coordinate.longitude];

            CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

            CLLocationDistance distance = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:restLocation];
            distance = distance/1000;

            NSString *sDistance = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%1.2f%@",@"Distance: ",distance, @" km"];

            cell.detailTextLabel.text = sDistance;
        }

    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You don't sort the cells actually. You need to sort the data used to populate the table view. Do this before loading the table view. Then the cells will appear in the same order as the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks rmaddy and steven.

I couldn't make geoCodeFromString work, so I have used google api to get coordinates for the addresses. I am modifying my json array of addresses to add distance key and then sorting this new array using NSSortDescriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Sort data source instead of Cell, change a little before cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate

```
json = [json sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    NSString *address1 = [obj1 objectForKey:@"Address"];
    NSString *address2 = [obj2 objectForKey:@"Address"];
    return [self distanceFromAddress:address1] > [self distanceFromAddress:address2];
}];

- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromAddress: (NSString *)sAddress {

//Put your Geocoder method here

}
```